# How to set read preference for gridFs in Java?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I want to connect my Java application with gridfs with read preference as secondaryPreferred, preferably using spring-data-mongodb 1.10.1

Comment: And what is the exact problem you've faced?

Comment: GridFsTemplate doesn't have a method to specify readpreference the way MongoTemplate does